# Laravel between clause returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I get a SQL in laravel like this

```
$scheduleMap=array("schedule_id"=>$scheduleId);
$scheduleConsume=DB::connection("mysql_report")->table("xxx")
->where($scheduleMap)
->whereBetween(DB::Raw("TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(report_time))"),array(DB::Raw("TO_DAYS('".$startDate."')"),DB::Raw("TO_DAYS('".$startDate."')")))
->select(DB::Raw("SUM(imp_num) as imp_num"))
->first();
```

and I printed SQL as

```
select SUM(imp_num) as imp_num from `xxx` 
where TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(report_time)) 
between TO_DAYS('2016-11-05') 
and TO_DAYS('2016-11-12')
```

Then I try to run sql in navicat,it works well,but in laravel,it return null.
I can't understand! I have to use whereRaw  now.

Comment: report_time is UNIXTIME

Comment: can you include your data structure with example data

Comment: As a note, you probably want to have all your date/time values in native `DATETIME` fields since the performance penalty for conversion can be very high.

Comment: for example,I want to get data limit by report_time between 2016-12-01 and 2016-12-03 ,and  the formated time may be 2016-12-03 03:11:23,but I got a param end_time 2016-12-03 ,I need to ignore the part after day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$scheduleConsume = DB::connection("mysql_report")
                     ->table('xxx')
                     ->where('schedule_id', $scheduleId)
                     ->whereBetween(
                        DB::Raw("TO_DAYS(FROM_UNIXTIME(report_time))"), [
                          DB::Raw("TO_DAYS('".$startDate."')"),DB::Raw("TO_DAYS('".$startDate."')")
                        ]
                      )
                     ->select(DB::Raw("SUM(imp_num) as imp_num"))
                     ->first();
```